# Unmet Dependencies on Lubuntu 13.10 Desktop

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a newbie to ROS and Linux.  I have Lubuntu 13.10 installed on my laptop and I want to install ROS.  When I go to install ROS (Precise version), I get "unmet dependencies" and the install fails.

Should I be installing ROS on Lubuntu in the first place?  This is an old laptop so I wanted as thin a version of Ubuntu as possible and I believe that Lubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) has the same core as Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise).

Am I headed in the right direction?  How can I resolve these "unmet dependencies"?  I believe the "sudo apt-get update" was successful.

Incidentally, these are the unmet dependencies I'm getting:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-hydro-desktop-full : Depends: ros-hydro-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: ros-hydro-mobile but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: ros-hydro-perception but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: ros-hydro-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99166/unmet-dependencies-on-lubuntu-13.10-desktop/) by [altemir](https://answers.ros.org/users/7486/altemir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2013-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out ...  As I now realize, Lubuntu 13.10 does not use the Ubuntu 12.04 core.  It uses the 13.10 core.  duh.  All I did was to reinstall Lubuntu, this time using the older 12.04 version, which is what ROS Hydro needs to work.  Installation went fine and it seems to be working.

---

Originally posted by [altemir](https://answers.ros.org/users/7486/altemir/) with karma: 48 on 2013-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2